# Difference between .navbar and .navbar a in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, navbar

what is the difference between that .navbar and .navbar a

```
   .navbar {
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333;
        font-family: Arial;
    }


    .navbar a {
        float: left;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

I can't get to find what the difference is between those. Please don't get irritated I am a noob at web technologies

Comment: Please read: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case .navbar is a css class that refers mostly to a parent element inside which your hyperlink is located (that is the `<a>` in your HTML file). It can be a div or some container element, that depends on your HTML.

While `.navbar a` refers to any `<a>` that is a child element inside a container element. Hyperlinks that are not children of `.navbar` elements will not be affected. For example, let's look at this html chunk:

```
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Click here!</a>
</div>
```

Let's say the above is part of your index.html file or so. In your css file:

```
.navbar {
  /*all css style here will affect your div class="navbar"*/
}
.navbar a {
  /*put something here to style all hyperlinks that are child to .navbar elements*/
}
```

Please let us know. You can check sites like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp) and read and read a lot, your skills will be largely improved with practice and reading.

Comment: how did yo do with this?

Answer (score 2):

If you have the below HTML

```
<div class="navbar">
     <p>Hello World>
     <a href="#"> Hello World</a>
</div>
```

`.navbar` will get applied to your div and then subsequently to everything that is within it

`.navbar a` will only get applied to the `<a>` tag inside the div with `class=navbar`

Answer (score 1):

To explain it consider the following html code:

```
<div class = "navbar">
    <a></a>
</div>
```

The first div will apply the following style:

```
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
font-family: Arial;
```

However `<a></a>` will apply the following style:

```
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
```

For `<a>` tag you need not to add any `class` attribute. It will automatically apply the style as you defined the style `.navbar a`